# javascript bugged repeating loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to English and Javascript try to understand what I said

The problem is when click it when it's between 1%-99% it flash back and forward,
I want to reset it, not adding a new one. When every time I click it, it will reset to 0% then stops at 100%. I just don't want it flash.

```js
function loader(x){
  if(x <= 100){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".bar").width(x + '%');
      $(".front .bar").text(x + "%");
      x++;
      loader(x);
    }, 1000 / 15);
  }
}
loader(0);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".progressbar-wrapper").click(function(){
    x = 0;
    loader(x);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
    background:#cccccc;
}
.progressbar-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.progressbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
.bar {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 5px rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar-wrapper">
     <div class="progressbar">
          <div class="side front">
               <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this,

you have to clear the previous timer,

Try below code.

Check **clearTimeout(time);** this line.

```js
var time=null;
function loader(x){
  if(x <= 100){
    time = setTimeout(function(){
      $(".bar").width(x + '%');
      $(".front .bar").text(x + "%");
      x++;
      loader(x);
    }, 1000 / 15);
  }
}
loader(0);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".progressbar-wrapper").click(function(){
    x = 0;
    clearTimeout(time);
    loader(x);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
    background:#cccccc;
}
.progressbar-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.progressbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
.bar {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 5px rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar-wrapper">
     <div class="progressbar">
          <div class="side front">
               <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix would be to have your `x` binding *outside* of the functions, such that when `x` is reassigned to `0` on a click, the `loader` can see the change. Because `loader` is recursive already, there's no need to initialize another `loader()` on click:

```js
let x = 0;

function loader() {
  if (x < 100) x++;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".bar").width(x + '%');
    $(".front .bar").text(x + "%");
    loader(x);
  }, 1000 / 15);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loader();
  $(".progressbar-wrapper").click(function() {
    x = 0;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.progressbar-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.progressbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 5px rgba(225, 0, 120, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar-wrapper">
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="side front">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it won't reset when it's at 100

Comment: Oh, your question implied you wanted the click to do something only when the percentage was between 1 and 99%. See edit, just don't cancel the timeout, and increment `x` when it's below 100